# node.js stdout clearline() and cursorTo() functions

Tags: node.js

From a node.js tutorial, I see those two process.stdout functions :

```
process.stdout.clearLine();
process.stdout.cursorTo(0);
```

But I'm using a more recent node.js version (4.2.4), and those functions do not exist. I get `process.stdout.clearLine is not a function` and `process.stdout.cursorTo is not a function`.

What is the equivalent of clearLine and cursorTo on node.js version 4.2.4 ?

EDIT :

Those are not working either :

```
process.readline.clearLine();
process.readline.cursorTo(0);

function writeWaitingPercent(p) {
    process.readline.clearLine();
    process.readline.cursorTo(0);
    process.stdout.write(`waiting ... ${p}%`);
}
```

I get `Cannot read property 'clearLine' of undefined`

Answer (score 56, accepted):

This is the solution :

First, require readline :

```
var readline = require('readline');
```

Then, use cursorTo like this :

```
function writeWaitingPercent(p) {
    //readline.clearLine(process.stdout);
    readline.cursorTo(process.stdout, 0);
    process.stdout.write(`waiting ... ${p}%`);
}
```

I've commented clearLine, since it's useless in my case (cursorTo move back the cursor to the start)

Comment: I had the same problem. When running from the terminal it works, when I run from WebStorm I need to require readline and use your method. Why is that?

Comment: Because `clearLine` and `cursorTo` are undefined when `process.stdout` is not a tty. And Node/NPM console in WebStorm is non-Tty, as node process is started with input/output streams redirection. Please see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-1933.

Comment: If you don't `clearLine` and you need to write a string of less length than the last output, you will still see the remainder trailing from the end.

Answer (score 31):

The [Readline module](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/readline.html) that is part of Node.js now provides `readline.cursorTo(stream, x, y)`, `readline.moveCursor(stream, dx, dy)` and `readline.clearLine(stream, dir)` methods.

---

With TypeScript, your code should look like this:

```
import * as readline from 'readline'
// import readline = require('readline') also works

/* ... */

function writeWaitingPercent(p: number) {
    readline.clearLine(process.stdout, 0)
    readline.cursorTo(process.stdout, 0, null)
    let text = `waiting ... ${p}%`
    process.stdout.write(text)
}
```

---

The previous code will transpile into the following Javascript (ES6) code:

```
const readline = require('readline');

/* ... */

function writeWaitingPercent(p) {
    readline.clearLine(process.stdout, 0);
    readline.cursorTo(process.stdout, 0, null);
    let text = `waiting ... ${p}%`;
    process.stdout.write(text);
}
```

---

As an alternative, you can use the following code for Javascript (ES6):

```
const readline = require('readline');

/* ... */

function waitingPercent(p) {
    readline.clearLine(process.stdout, 0)
    readline.cursorTo(process.stdout, 0)
    let text = `waiting ... ${p}%`
    process.stdout.write(text)
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me, it always appends and doesn't clear the line in webstorm.

Comment: for those who wanna clear multiple lines, change this `readline.cursorTo(<READ_LINE_STREAM>, 0, null)` for this `readline.cursorTo(<READ_LINE_STREAM>, 0, <NUMBER_OF_LINES>)` node 8.11.3 its working. https://stackoverflow.com/a/23777620/7173478

Answer (score 6):

if you see stdout exceptions like `TypeError: process.stdout.clearLine` is not a function in Debug Console window of Visual Studio Code (or Webstorm), run the app as external terminal application instead of internal console. The reason is that Debug Console window is not TTY (`process.stdout.isTTY` is false). Therefore update your launch configuration in `launch.json` with `"console": "externalTerminal"` option.

Answer (score 0):

For my part, I had the `clearline is not a function` error in a package that use `process.stdout.clearline()`.

I had to start my windows console as **administrator** to make it works.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to point out that you may also face this problem when running your Node application on Visual Studio Code! Running the same application on terminal will just work perfectly.

Answer (score -9):

process.readline.cursorTo and process.readline.clearLine

[Node v4.2.4 Documentation](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v4.x/docs/api/readline.html)

Comment: Weird, didn't test but got this on documentation.

Comment: When answering questions, don't reference documentation; instead show examples.

Comment: @Christopher'Solidus'DeJong I think it's nice to do both.