# process.stdout does't have function "clearLine" in childProcess

Tags: javascript, node.js

In the "Main.js", i use spawn to create a child_process.I want get data from "work.js",but it show error

```
TypeError: out.clearLine is not a function
```

If use `node work.js` in the terminal，it works fine。
It seems like process.stdout does't have function "clearLine" in childProcess.

main.js

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var child = spawn('node',['work.js']);
child.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log('data:',data.toString());
})
child.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log("stderr:", data.toString());
});
```

work.js

```
var out = process.stdout;
var idx = 0;
var id = setInterval(()=>{
    idx++;
    out.clearLine();
    out.cursorTo(0);
    out.write('workTime:' + idx);
    if(idx>3){
        clearInterval(id);  
        console.log();
        console.log('end')
    }
},100)
```

It's just a demo, i cant't change the work.js. How can i fix the problem in main.js,thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See: [node.js stdout clearline() and cursorTo() functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34570452/node-js-stdout-clearline-and-cursorto-functions)

```
var readline = require('readline');
function writeWaitingPercent(p) {
    //readline.clearLine(process.stdout);
    readline.cursorTo(process.stdout, 0);
    process.stdout.write(`waiting ... ${p}%`);
}
```