# What is the use of the cursorTo in the nodejs?

Tags: node.js

I read a file of nodejs and encountered a method cursorTo and I didn't understand it. Please someone explain.

```
function refreshConsole () {
    if (Settings.properties.preventMessageFlicker) {
        readline.cursorTo(process.stdout, 0, 0);
    } else {
        process.stdout.write('\033c');
    }
}
```

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34570452/node-js-stdout-clearline-and-cursorto-functions) may help u

Comment: Why there is three parameter in the cursorTo ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you see the Nodejs documentation for [cursorTo](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/readline.html#readline_readline_cursorto_stream_x_y), you will find following explanation:

> **readline.cursorTo(stream, x, y)**
>
> - stream < Writable >
> - x < number >
> - y < number >
>
> The readline.cursorTo() method moves cursor to the specified position
>   in a given TTY stream

If you want to understand how this really works, create a `test.js` file and copy paste below code in it. Execute in console using `node test.js`

```
process.stdin.resume();
process.stdin.setEncoding('utf8');

console.log('This is interactive console for cursorTo explanation');

process.stdin.on('data', function (data) {
   // This is when only x value is given as input 
    for(i = 0; i< 10; i++){
        console.log('here x = '+ i + ' and y = 0' );
        require('readline').cursorTo(process.stdout, i);
    }
    // This is when  x  and y values are given as input
    // for(i = 0; i< 10; i++){
    //     console.log('here x = '+ i + ' and y = '+ i );
    //     require('readline').cursorTo(process.stdout, i, i);
    // }
});

process.on('SIGINT', function(){
    process.stdout.write('\n end \n');
    process.exit();
});
```

- For the first for loop you will get the response as below:

  ```
  This is interactive console for cursorTo explanation
  hello
  here x = 0 and y = 0
  here x = 1 and y = 0
   here x = 2 and y = 0
    here x = 3 and y = 0
     here x = 4 and y = 0
      here x = 5 and y = 0
       here x = 6 and y = 0
        here x = 7 and y = 0
         here x = 8 and y = 0
          here x = 9 and y = 0
  ```
- This is because for each execution of `require('readline').cursorTo(process.stdout, i)`, the cursor will point to next line with respective `x-ordinate` we are giving and the `y-ordinate` is zero.
- For the second for loop(which is commented in the above code), we are passing both `x` and `y` ordinates. the output will be as follows:

  ```
  here x = 1 and y = 1console for cursorTo explanation
  hhere x = 2 and y = 2
  hehere x = 3 and y = 3
     here x = 4 and y = 4
      here x = 5 and y = 5
       here x = 6 and y = 6
        here x = 7 and y = 7
         here x = 8 and y = 8
          here x = 9 and y = 9
  ```
- You may notice in the second output `console for cursorTo explanation` is overlapped with text `here`. This is because when both the ordinates(`x` and `y`) are given, For `(0, 0)` it moves back to the point where its started that's near "*This is interactive console for cursorTo explanation*" and prints location, similarly for each ordinates it moves and prints data.